# "Offline mode" in iOS disabling radios

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

I want to put my iPhone on offline mode completely. That way no-one can find me using Cell Towers or GPS. I want to keep my phone on.

What is the best way for doing that?

Comment: Stack Exchange works best when there is one question to answer. You have 4 there, even though you only numbered the first 3. Please try to edit your post down to a single question, explain what research you have done so far & also perhaps why you are wanting to do this. See [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You know GPS is a one-way system, like a radio station? Your phone can see where it is, but GPS can't see your phone. Cell towers, on the other hand can always be triangulated from if your phone has a voice-capable connection. Your level of "offline" really depends on whether you're trying to hide from your mom, or the FBI ;)

Comment: This is a research and imagine that i want to hide myself from FBI :)

Comment: voice-capable connection? What is your mean? Mean that tower->provider can find my location when i am in airplane mode or not?

Comment: I saw some providers can change phone settings for gprs or mms or etc, So they can see your recieved gps data. am i right?

Comment: I think you need to go & do some research, then come back when you have a single clear question, rather than one question after another. If your question is "Is my position discoverable to a third party when I have Airplane mode enabled?" then the answer is "No".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching Airplane Mode on entirely disables the Wi-Fi, cellular and Bluetooth radios in your iPhone. To disable GPS as well, go to Settings → Privacy → Location Services and switch the toggle off.